# Angular Js ng-style Conditional evaluating px

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, pixel, ng-class

Trying to set the style of an element based on its height. (i.e., if height < X 'style 1', else 'style 2'.

The syntax is correct, but the evaluation of the height property of the  in pixels is the problem.

```
ng-class="{true:'panel panel-success', false:'panel panel-danger'}[documents.length > 0]"
```

works perfect, but

```
ng-class="{true:'panel panel-success', false:'panel panel-danger'}[height < 200px]"
```

does not work

Comment: Would `[parseInt(height) < 200]` work?

Answer (score 1):

`height < 200px` won't work because `200px` is non-numeric.

You could do this

```
<div class="panel" ng-class="height < 200 ? 'panel-success' : 'panel-danger'">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation : What you need is a directive !!

```
var elemstyle = angular.module('elemstyle', []);

elemstyle.controller('HeightBasedElCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){ 

  $scope.data = {
    maxH : 200
  };

}]);


elemstyle.directive('heightBasedCss', [function(){
  return {
    transclude : true,
    template : '<div ng-class="{true : \'panel panel-success\', false: \'panel panel-danger\'} [ checkHeight() ]" ng-transclude><div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        scope.checkHeight = function() {

            return elem[0].offsetHeight < scope.data.maxH; 
        };
    }  
  };
}]);
```

now all you have to do is use the directive :

```
<div height-based-css>
    <!-- 
        add whatever content you like here ... 
    -->
</div>
```

jsfiddle to try : http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/cL3Lda69/

jasmine test : http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/taakfhhs/

Note regarding jsfiddle version : I used binding on a textarea to see the style change in real time + TODO on jasmine ( test element offsetHeight changes)

Hope it helps.